# Como se puede imprimir en el pluguin de dataTable un Json bidimensional que se encuentra en el registro de una tabla

Tags: php, json, datatable, foreach, imprimir

Que tal buena dia: me explico estoy desarrollando un sistema donde recolecto de una Api un json bidimensional, limpio esos datos y los convierto en un string para guardarlos posteriormente en una base de datos de Mysql. Cuando quiero imprimir los datos en una tabla del pluguin dataTable como puedo recorrer ese arreglo sin que afecte las funciones del pluguin de la tabla lo explico en el siguiente código:

```php
<?php
require_once "../controladores/autentificacion.controlador.php"; // mando llamar los controladores y los metodos que conectan a la base de datos 
require_once "../modelos/autentificacion.modelo.php";

class TablaAutentificacion{

    /*=============================================
    Tabla Administradores
    =============================================*/ 

    public function mostrarTabla(){
        $respuesta = ControladorAutentificacion::ctrMostrarAutentificacion(null, null); // instancio el metodo para mandar llamar la informacion de la base de datos (respuesta) es un array que me devuelve una tabla con 6 atributos el cual uno de ellos que se llama datosJson ese campo vine con un json bidimencional

        if(count($respuesta) == 0){ // pregunto si viene algo en la tabla
            $datosJson = '{"data":[]}';
            echo $datosJson;
            return;
        } // si no me regresa los datos de la tabla 

        $datosJson = '{
    
            "data":[';

        foreach ($respuesta as $key => $value) { // recorro el resultado de la tabla mysql
            $jsonDatosApi = json_decode($value["dataJson"],true); // convierto en json el formato string que me devuelve la tabla
            foreach ($json as $key => $value) { // con un foreac recorro el json bidimensional 
                foreach ($value["items"] as $key => $value2) {
                    $imprimir = $value2["InspectionId"].'</br>'; // como imprimo este resiltado en la parte de abajo que dice aqui 
                }
            }
            $datosJson .='[
                        "'.($key+1).'",
                        "'.$value["nombreApi"].'",
                        "'.$value["token"].'",
                        "'.$value["estado"].'",
                        "'.$imprimir.'", // aqui necesito imprimir el resultado de todos los campos del json
                        ""
                        ],';
        }

        $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0, -1);
        $datosJson .= ']}';
        echo $datosJson;
    }
}

/*=============================================
Tabla Administradores
=============================================*/ 

$tabla = new TablaAutentificacion();
$tabla -> mostrarTabla();
```

Comment: puedes mejorar tu código por favor no se entiende... te he ayudado un poco metiéndolo dentro del resaltador pero sigue sin ser legible. pareciera ser un solo archivo pero como que no lo es al final ...

Comment: otro punto datatable tiene formas de rellenar una tabla mediante ajax ... por otro lado puedes rellenarla con una estructura html estatica.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo quieres mostrar esos datos en una datatable, para empezar debes utilizar por el lado del html en la configuración de datatable la propiedad "ajax" y colocar como valor el archivo php que maneja tú json, luego en este último archivo debes usar la función de php  json_encode y mostrarla con un "echo" .
Trata solo de hacer un echo json_decode($value["dataJson"]) y no coloques otro echo después, recuerda que el json para datatable tiene una estructura que debes respetar, de hecho puedes poblar datatable a mano siguiendo este ejemplo y cambiadolo con tús datos si no te funciona json_encode:

```
echo '{"data":[{"call_id":"none","start_date":"none","start_time":null,"call_duration":null,"direction":null,"ani":null,"dnis":null,"filename":null,"port_number":null}]}';
```